# How to retrieve Airflow connections in bulk using bash? (Google Composer)

Tags: bash, awk, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to create a composer environment with the approach of **infrastructure as code**.
For this, I need to be able to store and retrieve airflow variables programmatically, and keep them versioned somewhere.

The following command lets me list all my connections within the specified `$COMPOSER_ENV`

```
gcloud composer environments run `$COMPOSER_ENV` --location <location> connections -- --list
```

Here's the output :

```
╒════════════════════════════════╤═════════════════════════════╤════════════════════════════════╤════════╤════════════════╤══════════════════════╤════════════════════════════════╕
│ Conn Id                        │ Conn Type                   │ Host                           │ Port   │ Is Encrypted   │ Is Extra Encrypted   │ Extra                          │
╞════════════════════════════════╪═════════════════════════════╪════════════════════════════════╪════════╪════════════════╪══════════════════════╪════════════════════════════════╡
│ 'airflow_db'                   │ 'mysql'                     │ 'airflow-sqlp...rvice.default' │ None   │ True           │ False                │ None                           │
├────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ 'beeline_default'              │ 'beeline'                   │ 'localhost'                    │ 10000  │ False          │ True                 │ 'gAAAAABfdZs0...yjt7nj1C2Dzgm' │
├────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ 'bigquery_default'             │ 'google_cloud_platform'     │ None                           │ None   │ False          │ True                 │ 'gAAAAABfdZs2...AOdwY-EnZLg==' │
├────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ 'local_mysql'                  │ 'mysql'                     │ 'localhost'                    │ None   │ True           │ False                │ None                           │
├────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ 'presto_default'               │ 'presto'                    │ 'localhost'                    │ 3400   │ False          │ False                │ None                           │
├────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ 'google_cloud_default'         │ 'google_cloud_platform'     │ None                           │ None   │ False          │ True                 │ 'gAAAAABfdZs2...oMm2saUwAxQ==' │
├────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ 'hive_cli_default'             │ 'hive_cli'                  │ None                           │ None   │ False          │ False                │ None                           │
├────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ 'pig_cli_default'              │ 'pig_cli'                   │ None                           │ None   │ False          │ False                │ None                           │
├────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ 'hiveserver2_default'          │ 'hiveserver2'               │ 'localhost'                    │ 10000  │ False          │ False                │ None                           │
├────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ 'metastore_default'            │ 'hive_metastore'            │ 'localhost'                    │ 9083   │ False          │ True                 │ 'gAAAAABfdZs0...vNSgFh1mE1HY=' │
├────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ 'mongo_default'                │ 'mongo'                     │ 'mongo'                        │ 27017  │ False          │ False                │ None                           │
├────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ 'mysql_default'                │ 'mysql'                     │ 'mysql'                        │ None   │ False          │ False                │ None                           │
├────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ 'postgres_default'             │ 'postgres'                  │ 'postgres'                     │ None   │ True           │ False                │ None                           │
├────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ 'sqlite_default'               │ 'sqlite'                    │ '/tmp/sqlite_default.db'       │ None   │ False          │ False                │ None                           │
├────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ 'http_default'                 │ 'http'                      │ 'https://www.httpbin.org/'     │ None   │ False          │ False                │ None                           │
├────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ 'mssql_default'                │ 'mssql'                     │ 'localhost'                    │ 1433   │ False          │ False                │ None                           │
├────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ 'vertica_default'              │ 'vertica'                   │ 'localhost'                    │ 5433   │ False          │ False                │ None                           │
├────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ 'wasb_default'                 │ 'wasb'                      │ None                           │ None   │ False          │ True                 │ 'gAAAAABfdZs0...ST7E2347-uG4=' │
├────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ 'webhdfs_default'              │ 'hdfs'                      │ 'localhost'                    │ 50070  │ False          │ False                │ None                           │
├────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ 'ssh_default'                  │ 'ssh'                       │ 'localhost'                    │ None   │ False          │ False                │ None                           │
├────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ 'sftp_default'                 │ 'sftp'                      │ 'localhost'                    │ 22     │ False          │ True                 │ 'gAAAAABfdZs0...guLrr1ky5XpN2' │
├────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ 'fs_default'                   │ 'fs'                        │ None                           │ None   │ False          │ True                 │ 'gAAAAABfdZs0...WqhP9ZLa8gQ==' │
├────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ 'aws_default'                  │ 'aws'                       │ None                           │ None   │ False          │ False                │ None                           │
├────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ 'spark_default'                │ 'spark'                     │ 'yarn'                         │ None   │ False          │ True                 │ 'gAAAAABfdZs0...18ws2BelkcL8=' │
├────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ 'druid_broker_default'         │ 'druid'                     │ 'druid-broker'                 │ 8082   │ False          │ True                 │ 'gAAAAABfdZs0...sC6Kcd9mOKhE=' │
├────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ 'druid_ingest_default'         │ 'druid'                     │ 'druid-overlord'               │ 8081   │ False          │ True                 │ 'gAAAAABfdZs0...CpBdCkHuk5lqw' │
├────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ 'redis_default'                │ 'redis'                     │ 'redis'                        │ 6379   │ False          │ True                 │ 'gAAAAABfdZs0...E1qdjhMngIg==' │
├────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ 'sqoop_default'                │ 'sqoop'                     │ 'rmdbs'                        │ None   │ False          │ False                │ ''                             │
├────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ 'emr_default'                  │ 'emr'                       │ None                           │ None   │ False          │ True                 │ 'gAAAAABfdZs0...GsJIS8IjaBuM=' │
├────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ 'databricks_default'           │ 'databricks'                │ 'localhost'                    │ None   │ False          │ False                │ None                           │
├────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ 'qubole_default'               │ 'qubole'                    │ 'localhost'                    │ None   │ False          │ False                │ None                           │
├────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ 'segment_default'              │ 'segment'                   │ None                           │ None   │ False          │ True                 │ 'gAAAAABfdZs0...oawClUj4Qzj8i' │
├────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ 'azure_data_lake_default'      │ 'azure_data_lake'           │ None                           │ None   │ False          │ True                 │ 'gAAAAABfdZs0...DMIAMmOeZNg==' │
├────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ 'azure_cosmos_default'         │ 'azure_cosmos'              │ None                           │ None   │ False          │ True                 │ 'gAAAAABfdZs0...tusOfGrWviAk=' │
├────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ 'azure_contai...ances_default' │ 'azure_container_instances' │ None                           │ None   │ False          │ True                 │ 'gAAAAABfdZs0...q460BKvTu4Lk=' │
├────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ 'cassandra_default'            │ 'cassandra'                 │ 'cassandra'                    │ 9042   │ False          │ False                │ None                           │
├────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ 'dingding_default'             │ 'http'                      │ ''                             │ None   │ False          │ False                │ None                           │
├────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ 'opsgenie_default'             │ 'http'                      │ ''                             │ None   │ False          │ False                │ None                           │
├────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ 'google_cloud...store_default' │ 'google_cloud_platform'     │ None                           │ None   │ False          │ True                 │ 'gAAAAABfdZs2...ltsxQHWUgxA==' │
├────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ 'google_cloud_storage_default' │ 'google_cloud_platform'     │ None                           │ None   │ False          │ True                 │ 'gAAAAABfdZs2...RNLazPEE7gQ==' │
╘════════════════════════════════╧═════════════════════════════╧════════════════════════════════╧════════╧════════════════╧══════════════════════╧════════════════════════════════╛
```

The issue with this output is that it returns a hardly usable table of data (See image bellow). Ideally, it should return a json like structure.

- Question 1 : Is there a quick way to export (and import?) the connections (and variables) as a json?
- Question 2 : If Question 1 is "there isn't a way", then how do I turn this data into a beautiful dictionary or key-value like structure?

Also, any additional explanation on the `awk/grep` patterns would be very much appreciated.

Comment: @EdMorton no, the utilitary used in the answer is not available for earlier versions of airflow, and not at all for composer (at the moment). As composer caps at version 1.10.10, and the feature only exists in the 'latest' airflow v.

Comment: Sorry I'll clarify : I do need to convert the text to JSON. No, the answer bellow is not sufficient.

Comment: OK, then I posted an answer. Since you didn't provide expected output in your question I'm just guessing at what you want output but it should be very close if not precisely what you want.

Comment: could you check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64187737/4593654) works in composer?

Comment: For Airflow 1, please see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64173799/how-to-list-all-connections-clearly-within-composer-airflow/71712995?noredirect=1#comment126750810_71712995

Comment: For Airflow 1, please see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64173799/how-to-list-all-connections-clearly-within-composer-airflow/71712995?noredirect=1#comment126750810_71712995

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `cat file` instead of your `gcloud` command which I don't have to generate the table in your question:

```
$ cat tst.awk
!/[[:space:]]/ {
    # Skip all lines that separate the data rows
    next
}
(++nr) == 1 {
    # Set FS to whatever the combination of control chars is at the start of the first data line
    match($0,/[^[:blank:]]+/)
    FS = "[[:blank:]]*" substr($0,1,RLENGTH) "[[:blank:]]*"
}
{
    # Get rid of the FSs at the start and end of the line to avoid leading/trailing null fields
    gsub("^" FS "|" FS "$","")
}
nr == 1 {
    # Store the header lines for later use
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        gsub(/[[:blank:]]+/,"_",$i)
        hdr[i] = $i
    }
    print "{"
    next
}
{
    # Print the json-equivalent for the data on the current line
    gsub(/\047/,"\"")
    printf "%s  %s: {\n", (nr>2 ? ",\n" : ""), $1
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        printf "    \"%s\": %s%s\n", hdr[i], $i, (i<NF ? "," : "")
    }
    printf "  }", $1
}
END {
    print "\n}"
}
```

```
$ cat file | awk -f tst.awk
{
  "airflow_db": {
    "Conn_Type": "mysql",
    "Host": "airflow-sqlp...rvice.default",
    "Port": None,
    "Is_Encrypted": True,
    "Is_Extra_Encrypted": False,
    "Extra": None
  },
  "beeline_default": {
    "Conn_Type": "beeline",
    "Host": "localhost",
    "Port": 10000,
    "Is_Encrypted": False,
    "Is_Extra_Encrypted": True,
    "Extra": "gAAAAABfdZs0...yjt7nj1C2Dzgm"
  },
  "bigquery_default": {
    "Conn_Type": "google_cloud_platform",
    "Host": None,
    "Port": None,
    "Is_Encrypted": False,
    "Is_Extra_Encrypted": True,
    "Extra": "gAAAAABfdZs2...AOdwY-EnZLg=="
  },
  "local_mysql": {
    "Conn_Type": "mysql",
    "Host": "localhost",
    "Port": None,
    "Is_Encrypted": True,
    "Is_Extra_Encrypted": False,
    "Extra": None
  },
  "presto_default": {
    "Conn_Type": "presto",
    "Host": "localhost",
    "Port": 3400,
    "Is_Encrypted": False,
    "Is_Extra_Encrypted": False,
    "Extra": None
  },
  "google_cloud_default": {
    "Conn_Type": "google_cloud_platform",
    "Host": None,
    "Port": None,
    "Is_Encrypted": False,
    "Is_Extra_Encrypted": True,
    "Extra": "gAAAAABfdZs2...oMm2saUwAxQ=="
  },
  "hive_cli_default": {
    "Conn_Type": "hive_cli",
    "Host": None,
    "Port": None,
    "Is_Encrypted": False,
    "Is_Extra_Encrypted": False,
    "Extra": None
  },
  "pig_cli_default": {
    "Conn_Type": "pig_cli",
    "Host": None,
    "Port": None,
    "Is_Encrypted": False,
    "Is_Extra_Encrypted": False,
    "Extra": None
  },
  "hiveserver2_default": {
    "Conn_Type": "hiveserver2",
    "Host": "localhost",
    "Port": 10000,
    "Is_Encrypted": False,
    "Is_Extra_Encrypted": False,
    "Extra": None
  },
  "metastore_default": {
    "Conn_Type": "hive_metastore",
    "Host": "localhost",
    "Port": 9083,
    "Is_Encrypted": False,
    "Is_Extra_Encrypted": True,
    "Extra": "gAAAAABfdZs0...vNSgFh1mE1HY="
  },
  "mongo_default": {
    "Conn_Type": "mongo",
    "Host": "mongo",
    "Port": 27017,
    "Is_Encrypted": False,
    "Is_Extra_Encrypted": False,
    "Extra": None
  },
  "mysql_default": {
    "Conn_Type": "mysql",
    "Host": "mysql",
    "Port": None,
    "Is_Encrypted": False,
    "Is_Extra_Encrypted": False,
    "Extra": None
  },
  "postgres_default": {
    "Conn_Type": "postgres",
    "Host": "postgres",
    "Port": None,
    "Is_Encrypted": True,
    "Is_Extra_Encrypted": False,
    "Extra": None
  },
  "sqlite_default": {
    "Conn_Type": "sqlite",
    "Host": "/tmp/sqlite_default.db",
    "Port": None,
    "Is_Encrypted": False,
    "Is_Extra_Encrypted": False,
    "Extra": None
  },
  "http_default": {
    "Conn_Type": "http",
    "Host": "https://www.httpbin.org/",
    "Port": None,
    "Is_Encrypted": False,
    "Is_Extra_Encrypted": False,
    "Extra": None
  },
  "mssql_default": {
    "Conn_Type": "mssql",
    "Host": "localhost",
    "Port": 1433,
    "Is_Encrypted": False,
    "Is_Extra_Encrypted": False,
    "Extra": None
  },
  "vertica_default": {
    "Conn_Type": "vertica",
    "Host": "localhost",
    "Port": 5433,
    "Is_Encrypted": False,
    "Is_Extra_Encrypted": False,
    "Extra": None
  },
  "wasb_default": {
    "Conn_Type": "wasb",
    "Host": None,
    "Port": None,
    "Is_Encrypted": False,
    "Is_Extra_Encrypted": True,
    "Extra": "gAAAAABfdZs0...ST7E2347-uG4="
  },
  "webhdfs_default": {
    "Conn_Type": "hdfs",
    "Host": "localhost",
    "Port": 50070,
    "Is_Encrypted": False,
    "Is_Extra_Encrypted": False,
    "Extra": None
  },
  "ssh_default": {
    "Conn_Type": "ssh",
    "Host": "localhost",
    "Port": None,
    "Is_Encrypted": False,
    "Is_Extra_Encrypted": False,
    "Extra": None
  },
  "sftp_default": {
    "Conn_Type": "sftp",
    "Host": "localhost",
    "Port": 22,
    "Is_Encrypted": False,
    "Is_Extra_Encrypted": True,
    "Extra": "gAAAAABfdZs0...guLrr1ky5XpN2"
  },
  "fs_default": {
    "Conn_Type": "fs",
    "Host": None,
    "Port": None,
    "Is_Encrypted": False,
    "Is_Extra_Encrypted": True,
    "Extra": "gAAAAABfdZs0...WqhP9ZLa8gQ=="
  },
  "aws_default": {
    "Conn_Type": "aws",
    "Host": None,
    "Port": None,
    "Is_Encrypted": False,
    "Is_Extra_Encrypted": False,
    "Extra": None
  },
  "spark_default": {
    "Conn_Type": "spark",
    "Host": "yarn",
    "Port": None,
    "Is_Encrypted": False,
    "Is_Extra_Encrypted": True,
    "Extra": "gAAAAABfdZs0...18ws2BelkcL8="
  },
  "druid_broker_default": {
    "Conn_Type": "druid",
    "Host": "druid-broker",
    "Port": 8082,
    "Is_Encrypted": False,
    "Is_Extra_Encrypted": True,
    "Extra": "gAAAAABfdZs0...sC6Kcd9mOKhE="
  },
  "druid_ingest_default": {
    "Conn_Type": "druid",
    "Host": "druid-overlord",
    "Port": 8081,
    "Is_Encrypted": False,
    "Is_Extra_Encrypted": True,
    "Extra": "gAAAAABfdZs0...CpBdCkHuk5lqw"
  },
  "redis_default": {
    "Conn_Type": "redis",
    "Host": "redis",
    "Port": 6379,
    "Is_Encrypted": False,
    "Is_Extra_Encrypted": True,
    "Extra": "gAAAAABfdZs0...E1qdjhMngIg=="
  },
  "sqoop_default": {
    "Conn_Type": "sqoop",
    "Host": "rmdbs",
    "Port": None,
    "Is_Encrypted": False,
    "Is_Extra_Encrypted": False,
    "Extra": ""
  },
  "emr_default": {
    "Conn_Type": "emr",
    "Host": None,
    "Port": None,
    "Is_Encrypted": False,
    "Is_Extra_Encrypted": True,
    "Extra": "gAAAAABfdZs0...GsJIS8IjaBuM="
  },
  "databricks_default": {
    "Conn_Type": "databricks",
    "Host": "localhost",
    "Port": None,
    "Is_Encrypted": False,
    "Is_Extra_Encrypted": False,
    "Extra": None
  },
  "qubole_default": {
    "Conn_Type": "qubole",
    "Host": "localhost",
    "Port": None,
    "Is_Encrypted": False,
    "Is_Extra_Encrypted": False,
    "Extra": None
  },
  "segment_default": {
    "Conn_Type": "segment",
    "Host": None,
    "Port": None,
    "Is_Encrypted": False,
    "Is_Extra_Encrypted": True,
    "Extra": "gAAAAABfdZs0...oawClUj4Qzj8i"
  },
  "azure_data_lake_default": {
    "Conn_Type": "azure_data_lake",
    "Host": None,
    "Port": None,
    "Is_Encrypted": False,
    "Is_Extra_Encrypted": True,
    "Extra": "gAAAAABfdZs0...DMIAMmOeZNg=="
  },
  "azure_cosmos_default": {
    "Conn_Type": "azure_cosmos",
    "Host": None,
    "Port": None,
    "Is_Encrypted": False,
    "Is_Extra_Encrypted": True,
    "Extra": "gAAAAABfdZs0...tusOfGrWviAk="
  },
  "azure_contai...ances_default": {
    "Conn_Type": "azure_container_instances",
    "Host": None,
    "Port": None,
    "Is_Encrypted": False,
    "Is_Extra_Encrypted": True,
    "Extra": "gAAAAABfdZs0...q460BKvTu4Lk="
  },
  "cassandra_default": {
    "Conn_Type": "cassandra",
    "Host": "cassandra",
    "Port": 9042,
    "Is_Encrypted": False,
    "Is_Extra_Encrypted": False,
    "Extra": None
  },
  "dingding_default": {
    "Conn_Type": "http",
    "Host": "",
    "Port": None,
    "Is_Encrypted": False,
    "Is_Extra_Encrypted": False,
    "Extra": None
  },
  "opsgenie_default": {
    "Conn_Type": "http",
    "Host": "",
    "Port": None,
    "Is_Encrypted": False,
    "Is_Extra_Encrypted": False,
    "Extra": None
  },
  "google_cloud...store_default": {
    "Conn_Type": "google_cloud_platform",
    "Host": None,
    "Port": None,
    "Is_Encrypted": False,
    "Is_Extra_Encrypted": True,
    "Extra": "gAAAAABfdZs2...ltsxQHWUgxA=="
  },
  "google_cloud_storage_default": {
    "Conn_Type": "google_cloud_platform",
    "Host": None,
    "Port": None,
    "Is_Encrypted": False,
    "Is_Extra_Encrypted": True,
    "Extra": "gAAAAABfdZs2...RNLazPEE7gQ=="
  }
}
```

Note that idk if that's actually valid json or not, I'm just moving blocks of text from positions in your input to positions in your output. Hopefully it'll be easy enough for you to make whatever changes you need to make to produce whatever output you actually wanted to get (which was missing from your question).

Comment: Jesus christ.. this is beautiful. Now, all that needs to be figured out, is how to print the `...` present within the data, as the information is incomplete this way.

Comment: But that is a problem within composer/airflow :/

Comment: Look within `"Extra" : "gAAAAABfdZs2...AOdwY-EnZLg=="` the string is too long, so it has been replaced with `...` within it. But of course, this is a problem of airflow/composer outputting it this way.

Comment: But you know that has absolutely nothing to do with the script I provided, and nothing that could be fixed by a script running on the input you provided, right?

Comment: Obviously, but it is part of the question. Your script will be the one I use once I figure out this last part.

Comment: You should post that part as a separate question since it's completely unrelated to the question I answered. You'll get the best out of this forum if you only ask 1 question per question.

Comment: I think I'll do that.

Answer (score 2):

For Airflow 1

1. Connect to correct pod

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials PROJECT_PATH  --zone ZONE
```

PROJECT_PATH is something like projects/..../..gke : this is the value of GKE cluster field in the Environment detail section

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
```

2. From the NAMESPACE column take the name of a composer-* row and from the NAME column take the name of an airflow-worker-* row. Then connect to the worker as follows:

```
kubectl exec -itn composer-1-10-0-airflow-1-10-6-5983e0fe airflow-worker-8d8c49c87-9v7c4 -- /bin/bash
```

3. Once inside the worker, connect to database shell.

```
airflow shell
```

NOTE: If `shell` command is not available, use the instruction on  https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/access-airflow-database#airflow-1 to access the database.
And then run the SQL

```
select   json_arrayagg(
            json_object(
             'id', id,
             'conn_id', conn_id,
             'conn_type', conn_type,
             'host', host,
             'login',login,
             'password',password,
             'port',port,
             'extra', extra,
             'is_encrypted', is_encrypted,
             'is_extra_encrypted', is_extra_encrypted,
             'schema',IFNULL(`schema`, null)
           )
        ) as json_result
from (select * from connection  ) x;
```

Answer (score 1):

As I can see you want to export your connections to a *.json* file.

Currently, according to the [documentation](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/connection/index.html#exporting-connections-from-the-cli), using the latest and the stable version of Airflow , you can export the connections to a *.json* file. The command is as follows,

```
airflow connections export connections.json
```

Or,

```
airflow connections export /tmp/connections --format json
```

The .json format uses the schema,

```
{
  "airflow_db": {
    "conn_type": "mysql",
    "host": "mysql",
    "login": "root",
    "password": "plainpassword",
    "schema": "airflow",
    "port": null,
    "extra": null
  },
  "druid_broker_default": {
    "conn_type": "druid",
    "host": "druid-broker",
    "login": null,
    "password": null,
    "schema": null,
    "port": 8082,
    "extra": "{\"endpoint\": \"druid/v2/sql\"}"
  }
}
```

In addition, each connection is store in a environment variable respecting this naming convention: `AIRFLOW_CONN_{CONN_ID}`, [here](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/connection/index.html#storing-a-connection-in-environment-variables).

Comment: Thank you for the useful information, which could be helpful for the latest version users. Unfortunately, I am using Cloud composer, more specifically version 1.10.9 of airflow, which doesn't seem to support this feature.

Comment: @Aetos, in order to use the new feature releases I recommend you to upgrade your Composer Airflow environment, such as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/upgrading) ([refer to the release notes](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/release-notes)).