# How to list all connections clearly within composer/airflow?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to create a composer environment with the approach of **infrastructure as code**. For this, I need to store and retrieve airflow variables programmatically and keep them versioned somewhere.

In a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64159695/how-to-retrieve-airflow-connections-in-bulk-using-bash-google-composer), [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) wrote a script to convert the table to a JSON, but there is a problem related to the way composer/airflow outputs the data when using the following command :

```
gcloud composer environments run `$COMPOSER_ENV` --location <location> connections -- --list
```

A sample of the output is :

```
╒════════════════════════════════╤═════════════════════════════╤════════════════════════════════╤════════╤════════════════╤══════════════════════╤════════════════════════════════╕
│ Conn Id                        │ Conn Type                   │ Host                           │ Port   │ Is Encrypted   │ Is Extra Encrypted   │ Extra                          │
╞════════════════════════════════╪═════════════════════════════╪════════════════════════════════╪════════╪════════════════╪══════════════════════╪════════════════════════════════╡
│ 'airflow_db'                   │ 'mysql'                     │ 'airflow-sqlp...rvice.default' │ None   │ True           │ False                │ None                           │
├────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
```

As you can see, the problem is the `Host`, and `Extra` columns contain an ellipsis `...` that abridges long text such as here `'airflow-sqlp...rvice.default'`.

How do I get a full version of the information output by the above-mentioned (`composer`) utility?

I am using `composer-1.12.1-airflow-1.10.9`. Unfortunately the [nice feature of exporting the connections to a JSON using the CLI is only available in the latest version of airflow](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/connection/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

Am working on Airflow but never used composer. However, from the documentation came to know that `gcloud composer environments run` runs Airflow CLI sub-commands remotely.

Airflow CLI has an option to open DB shell `airflow shell` and its capable of receiving input from `stdin`. So I tried to pipe in SQL statement to retrieve connections and it worked.

```sh
> echo "select * from connection limit 3;" | airflow shell
/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/airflow-demo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:761: DeprecationWarning: You have two airflow.cfg files: /Users/arunvelsriram/airflow/airflow.cfg and /Users/arunvelsriram/spikes/airflow/airflow-demo/airflow_home/airflow.cfg. Airflow used to look at ~/airflow/airflow.cfg, even when AIRFLOW_HOME was set to a different value. Airflow will now only read /Users/arunvelsriram/spikes/airflow/airflow-demo/airflow_home/airflow.cfg, and you should remove the other file
  category=DeprecationWarning,
DB: sqlite:///airflow_home/airflow.db
1|airflow_db|mysql|mysql|airflow|root||||0|0
2|beeline_default|beeline|localhost|default|||10000|{"use_beeline": true, "auth": ""}|0|0
3|bigquery_default|google_cloud_platform||default|||||0|0
```

We could also extract the results as `json` or `csv`. Most databases supports it. For example in sqlite:

```sh
> echo "select
json_group_array(
        json_object(
        'id', id,
        'conn_id', conn_id,
        'conn_type', conn_type,
        'host', host, 'schema', schema,
        'login', login,
        'password', password,
        'port', port,
        'extra', extra,
        'is_encrypted', is_encrypted,
        'is_extra_encrypted', is_extra_encrypted
    )
) as json_result
from (select * from connection limit 3);" | airflow shell
/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/airflow-demo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:761: DeprecationWarning: You have two airflow.cfg files: /Users/arunvelsriram/airflow/airflow.cfg and /Users/arunvelsriram/spikes/airflow/airflow-demo/airflow_home/airflow.cfg. Airflow used to look at ~/airflow/airflow.cfg, even when AIRFLOW_HOME was set to a different value. Airflow will now only read /Users/arunvelsriram/spikes/airflow/airflow-demo/airflow_home/airflow.cfg, and you should remove the other file
  category=DeprecationWarning,
DB: sqlite:///airflow_home/airflow.db
[{"id":1,"conn_id":"airflow_db","conn_type":"mysql","host":"mysql","schema":"airflow","login":"root","password":null,"port":null,"extra":null,"is_encrypted":0,"is_extra_encrypted":0},{"id":2,"conn_id":"beeline_default","conn_type":"beeline","host":"localhost","schema":"default","login":null,"password":null,"port":10000,"extra":"{\"use_beeline\": true, \"auth\": \"\"}","is_encrypted":0,"is_extra_encrypted":0},{"id":3,"conn_id":"bigquery_default","conn_type":"google_cloud_platform","host":null,"schema":"default","login":null,"password":null,"port":null,"extra":null,"is_encrypted":0,"is_extra_encrypted":0}]
```

I couldn't try it composer as I don't have a composer environment. This is just a trick that I could think of since current version of Airflow CLI doesn't have configurable output.

Comment: This is brilliant ! I'll try it tomorrow and give you a feedback ;) thanks

Comment: just chance json_group_array to json_arrayagg. Rest should be fine

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the excellent solution of @savsr, here are the steps before his solution. You can run the following commands in Cloud Shell.

According to the Google Cloud Platform [docs](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/testing-dags#error-check):

You can get all the pods by performing the following command:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
```

Next, look for a pod with a name like `airflow-worker-1a2b3c-x0yz`.

Let's assume that this pod has namespace `composer-1-6-0-airflow-example-namespace`. Then you'll connect to it and get into a bash shell by performing the following command:

```
kubectl -n composer-1-6-0-airflow-example-namespace \ 
  exec -it airflow-worker-1a2b3c-x0yz -c airflow-worker -- /bin/bash
```

Now that you are inside this specific airflow worker, in a bash shell, you can perform the commands that @savsr has mentioned.

This I tried and it worked for me:

```
echo "select * from connection limit 3;" | airflow shell
```

Also, you may perform a more limiting query that will give you exactly the host names that you want:

```
echo "select host from connection limit 3;" | airflow shell
```

which in my example yielded:

```
host
airflow-sqlproxy-service.default
localhost
NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Connect to correct pod

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials PROJECT_PATH  --zone ZONE
```

PROJECT_PATH is something like projects/..../..gke : this is the value of GKE cluster field in the Environment detail section

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
```

2. From the NAMESPACE column take the name of a composer-* row and from the NAME column take the name of an airflow-worker-* row. Then connect to the worker as follows:

```
kubectl exec -itn composer-1-10-0-airflow-1-10-6-5983e0fe airflow-worker-8d8c49c87-9v7c4 -- /bin/bash
```

3. Once inside the worker, connect to database shell

```
airflow shell
```

NOTE: If `shell` command is not available, use the instruction on  https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/access-airflow-database#airflow-1 to access the database.
And then run the SQL

```
select   json_arrayagg(
            json_object(
             'id', id,
             'conn_id', conn_id,
             'conn_type', conn_type,
             'host', host,
             'login',login,
             'password',password,
             'port',port,
             'extra', extra,
             'is_encrypted', is_encrypted,
             'is_extra_encrypted', is_extra_encrypted,
             'schema',IFNULL(`schema`, null)
           )
        ) as json_result
from (select * from connection  ) x;
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: @LajosArpad Please see the edits