# How to list all connection & import a json list of connections in Cloud composer 2 Airflow 2

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, command-line-interface, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to list all connections in Cloud composer, view its value via cli command and also import another connections.json to Composer 2.

I am not able to find it relevant CLI commands in the [gcp composer doc](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/manage-airflow-connections).

Tried executing the below command.

```
gcloud composer environments run airflow-staging \
    --location us-east1 \
     connections -- --list
```

> ERROR: (gcloud.composer.environments.run) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Found 1
> problem:
> 1) Airflow CLI command: 'connections' is not supported in Cloud Composer.

Comment: I think it's not possible to list the connections with a `gcloud composer` command. You can check this link, but we need to be connected to a pod, to be able to add a query to list all the connections : 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64173799/how-to-list-all-connections-clearly-within-composer-airflow